# Including distutils in a py2app bundle

Tags: python, macos, distutils, py2app

I have a script that installs Python, and then installs some modules modules with:

`subprocess.call("python setup.py install")`

It works OK on windows with py2exe. But with Mac, using py2app, I get the following error when installing the additional modules:

```
File setup.py
    from distutils.core import setup
ImportError: No module named distutils.core
```

I tried explicitly including distutils when building the .app bundle, with `python setup.py py2app --packages distutils`, but then I get this error:

```
error: invalid command 'install'
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing env={} for MacOS.

I found you need env=None for Windows and env={} for MacOS for some reason. I was trying to launch Pylint in the local Python from an app running through py2exe on Windows and py2app on MacOS (and via egg install on Linux).